# Rails: updating the screen for every user on the current view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a Ruby on Rails application and I am in a situation I've never handled before. The thing is:

I am making a Task Manager, and whenever a task is created, the current view has to be updated for every user that is present, so the update is in real-time. For example: if I create a task, I should not be the only one to receive the screen update (which I have accomplished with AJAX), every user's screen that actually is on the same view has to be updated. How can I do this? Where do I start? Thank you!

Comment: If you're using Rails 5, you can use websockets with ActionCable, take a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ActionCable that is in-built feature of Rails 5 for real-time update. See docs: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html